# How to change Logo icon on DJI UI SDK's Status Bar DULStatusBarViewController in Swift?

Tags: dji-sdk

In the DJI demo code,

```
var statusBarVC = DULStatusBarViewController()
guard let preflightChecklistWidget = self.statusBarVC.widget(at: 1) else {
        return;
    }
```

We can get the widget object. But I am not sure how to change the DJI logo.

Can I create a new widget to replace it?

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/introduction/ui_library_introduction.html#asset-swap

According to the documentation, you need to swap out the assets. They need to keep the same name and pixel dimensions as the originals.